# Slick 3.1.1 sql PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "" + ""

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I have the following simple (and tested in Postgres) query that leads to the above error and I can't find what it is.

```
def findActiveByProviderKeyAndEmail(providerKey: String, email: String): Future[Option[UserRow]] = {
  val action = sql"""SELECT t1.* FROM user t1 " +
                     "WHERE t1.active=true AND " +
                     "      t1.email=$email AND " +
                     "      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM linked_account t2 " +
                     "              WHERE t2.user_id=t1.id AND " +
                     "                    t2.provider_key=$providerKey)""".as[UserRow].headOption
  db.run(action)
}
```

Note that before I was using `${User.baseTableRow.tableName}` instead of `user` and `${LinkedAccount.baseTableRow.tableName}` instead of `linked_account` but removed that to exclude possibilities of error.

The full runtime error is the following:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "" +
                       ""
  Position: 26]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
        at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "" +
                       ""
  Position: 26
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:157)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementProxy.execute(PreparedStatementProxy.java:44)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.execute(PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.java)
        at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:39)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is wrong - here is how multiline strings are done in Scala: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch01s03.html

In other words, it should be something like:

```
def findActiveByProviderKeyAndEmail(providerKey: String, email: String): Future[Option[UserRow]] = {
  val action = sql"""SELECT t1.* FROM user t1
                     WHERE t1.active=true AND
                           t1.email=$email AND
                           EXISTS (SELECT * FROM linked_account t2
                                   WHERE t2.user_id=t1.id AND
                t2.provider_key=$providerKey)""".as[UserRow].headOption
db.run(action)
}
```